# Magento - Trouble getting Sidebar navigation to show on category pages

Tags: php, xml, magento

This is perplexing me somewhat.
I'm on magento 1.7.

I have a left sidebar on all pages, and I'm trying to add a vertical navigation block to this side bar, to appear on all pages. So far, through editing catalog.xml, I can get it to appear on the front page, and the individual product pages, but it disappears when I visit a category page (the one that lists all the products in a category). When I try to add this block in via the "Custom Design" option for the category in the backend, it inserts the block into the sidebar 5 times, one on top of the other.

In catalog xml, right under < !-- Mage_Catalog -->

```
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/navigation/vert_nav.phtml" before="cart_sidebar" />
```

I think I've tried placing this is every place in catalog.xml that seemed to make sense, but I just can't figure out why I can't target the categories, and why the multiple blocks problem is happening.

I have also tried to add the block to page.xml, and although that works for the front page, it doesn't for the categories.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check if you have done as follows correctly.

On catalog.xml search `Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)` and locate `<reference name="left">`

by default it is

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Change it to

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.vert_nav" template="catalog/navigation/vert_nav.phtml" before="catalog.leftnav" />
</reference>
```

Do same for `Catalog Category (Anchor)`

Hope above helps.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out to be an anchor page that was causing the problem, refusing to accept the update. I simply changed the page type in the backend to non anchor and then the update applied. I still don't understand why my catalog xml wasn't working in the anchor section, despite doing just as you've explained. Anyway, onwards and upwards, thanks for your time.